# How to set multiple themes to an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-theme

I'm trying to set different themes each time the user loads a certain `Activity`.

I created a method to switch between 3 themes:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRandomTheme();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private void setRandomTheme() {
    int NUMBER_OF_THEMES = 3;
    int theme_ID = (int) (Math.random() * NUMBER_OF_THEMES);
    setTheme(Provider.getTheme(theme_ID));
}
```

But I have to declare a `android:theme` related to the Activity in the *AndroidManifest.xml* and so I can't simply switch the themes like that.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the theme before super.onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRandomTheme();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

private void setRandomTheme() {
    int NUMBER_OF_THEMES = 3;
    int theme_ID = (int) (Math.random() * NUMBER_OF_THEMES);
    setTheme(Provider.getTheme(theme_ID));
}
```

Comment: No, that's not the problem here